# error in AWK while specifying the filename

Tags: linux, awk

I am getting the error while mentioning the filename to the AWK.

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS="\n\nFrom";}{print $0 > NR".txt";}END{print NR;}'" $MAIL_DIR/mail.txt"
```

[image: Error]

Comment: start with giving space between awk statement closing `'` and `"filename"`

Comment: Please copy'n'paste the error into the question.  The screen image is unreadable!

Comment: You need to put a space after the close quote of the script, and you're unlikely to want the space at the start of the file name, leading to: `awk 'BEGIN {RS="\n\nFrom";}{print $0 > NR".txt";}END{print NR;}' "$MAIL_DIR/mail.txt"`

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the last two quotation marks. The path doesn't need that.

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS="\n\nFrom";}{print $0 > NR".txt";}END{print NR;}' $MAIL_DIR/mail.txt
```

But if you prefer to keep quotation marks, this will work as well:

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS="\n\nFrom";}{print $0 > NR".txt";}END{print NR;}' "$MAIL_DIR/mail.txt"
```

Comment: It is best to quote `"$MAIL_DIR/mail.txt"` as although the path may not have any spaces today, it may acquire them tomorrow.  With the double quotes present, that won't present any issues; if they're missing, then you'll have to add them.  The same goes for essentially all variable references — enclose in double quotes unless there's a reason not to.